# MongoDB: query for a field

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to query the "Username" field of this document in a MongoDB collection. The collection name is called uploads.

Here is the data

```
{
"Timestamp": "2013-08-06T09:45:02.5677852-04:00",
"Operator": {
    "Id": "94132d0b-f915-4205-a3b5-088dc017b9da",
    "Username": "test",
    "PasswordSha256": "590561e975aa1cbdaa6ff00da013dfb85656990eef11e504e9febe48a87d3642",
    "FullName": "test",
    "Enabled": "true",
    "OperatorPrivilegeEnum": "Administrator",
    "PasswordExpirationDate": "2013-11-04T09:40:51.7867096-05:00"
},
"AuditType": "GeneratedReport",
"Value": "Printed Setup Report on 6-Aug-2013 at 09:44:47"
}
```

I tried using

```
db.uploads.find({"Operator": {"Username": "test"}})
```

and,

```
db.uploads.find({"Operator": {$elemMatch: {"Username": "test"}}})
```

I'm not sure if the formatting of the document is messed up or not.

I need to find the Username from within Operator for part of my application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use dot notation in your query object key for that:

```
db.uploads.find({"Operator.Username": "test"})
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I didn't know you could use dot notation in Mongo, I am researching that now.